# iOS 10 How to set UNotificationContent threadIdentifier for remote notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationrequest

**TL;DR:** What key needs to be set in the APNs notification payload JSON to correspond to the `threadIdentifier` property of the `UNNotificationContent` object? e.g. the `"category"` key corresponds to the `categoryIdentifier` property.

---

iOS 10 introduces the `Notification Content Extension` allowing us to present a view controller when a notification is expanded.

The view controller that we provide conforms to the `UNNotificationContentExtension` protocol, that requires us to implement the `didReceive(_:)` method.

The documentation for this method includes the following paragraph:

> This method may be called multiple times while your view controller is visible. Specifically, it is called again when a new notification arrives whose ***threadIdentifier*** value matches the thread identifier of the notification already being displayed.

The `threadIdentifier` property may be set in code for local notifications, but I don't know how to set it for remote notifications that are sent from the server to APNs.

The `UNNotificationContent` documentation describes the property here: http://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent

The following JSON includes the keys I've tried (`"thread"` and `"thread-identifier"`):

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Hello World!",
        "sound" : "default",
        "category" : "example-category",
        "thread" : "example-thread",
        "thread-identifier" : "example-thread-identifier"
    }
    "custom-field" : "some value",
}
```

I can't find any documentation from Apple about how to set this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

I discovered from a contact at Apple that the correct key to populate this property is the `"thread-id"` key.

So the JSON sent to APNs is as follows:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Hello World!",
        "sound" : "default",
        "category" : "example-category",
        "thread-id" : "my conversation blah blah"
    }
    "custom-field" : "some value",
}
```

This populates the `threadIdentifier` property of the `UNNotificationContent` object accessible in your Notification Content Extension via `notification.request.content.threadIdentifier`.

By setting this `"thread-id"` value, it means that the `didReceive(_:)` method of your content extension will be multiple times. First when expanding the notification initially, and again whenever a new notification arrives with the same `"thread-id"` value.

I assume (hope) this will be added to the official documentation once iOS 10 is officially released.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-guardian-mobile-innovation-lab/how-to-replace-the-content-of-an-ios-notification-2d8d93766446 says to use apns-collapse-id

Comment: yes, this post is from a long time ago. apns-collapse-id isn't a key in the aps JSON. it has to be sent in the HTTP Header

Comment: it's used to collapse notifications since iOS 10. but i believe (not sure) that the "thread-id" key should be used to group messages in iOS 12 (new grouping fctinlty)

Comment: should it work with https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send in postman? I have set it there with a string and number but its still not working