# FCM - Remove Older Push Notifcation Tiles when a new Push Notiifcation is recieved

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in Xamarin Forms and is working as expected. But I want to removed all the notifications from the notification tray when a new push is received.

I have tried using the same collapse_key, but all the messages are received instead of the recent push.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using [`tag`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)?

Comment: @AL. yes , I tried giving "tag" in the key value pair in the custom option with the same string , but again got 2 messages instead of 1

Comment: The `tag` parameter should be in the `notification` payload, not in `data` (custom key-value pair) payload. Are you perhaps using the Firebase Notification Console to send the message? If yes, then you won't be able to set the `tag` parameter there. Try using [curl or Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/drafts/127316).

Comment: @AL. How can we achieve the same in iOS , any idea?

Comment: It works differently for iOS. Haven't tried it myself, but you're going to have to use a `thread-id`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433876/4625829)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should proceed with using the `tag` parameter, keeping in mind that it should be in the `notification` payload, not in the `data` (custom key-value pair) payload.

If you are using the Firebase Notification Console to send the message, then you won't be able to set the `tag` parameter there. Try using curl or Postman to send the message.