# Can you expire / remove a message remotely on FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using FCM for my push messages. Its great, however I've a client that needs to be able to remove a push message once its sent - (in case of mistakes / typos etc).

I know you can get the message id from when the Topic is queued to send messages, just wondering if there is a way to then use that ID to expire those messages remotely. i.e. to delete the message.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to delete/remove a message from the server side/console. The `message_id` is just an identifier that the message was sent successfully to the FCM server.

What is usually used for this scenario is the `tag` parameter (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45141994/4625829)) where an existing notification with the same tag gets replaced with the newer one.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this pretty much answer your question, feel free to tick it as correct so that your post would be properly tagged. Cheers!

Comment: I'll try it out this afternoon :). I think that what you suggest works. What I'll do with that then is that if an item is deleted. I can replace the notification with a new one that expires after a second .e.g (Deleted) . Then in other cases would just update the notification. Oh and of course I'll mark it solved!

Answer (score 2):

There are scenarios where you might want a replacing notification to notify the user rather than silently update. Chat applications are a good example. In this case you should set `tag` and `renotify` to true.

write this code on your `sw.js`

```
    const title = 'Notification 2 of 2';
    const options = {
      tag: 'renotify',
      renotify: true
    };
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
```

> You can test demo on [here](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/) by clicking in `renotify` button

Comment: Cool thank you. Thats good to know. Might be times when theres an important update or "Breaking News! Update" style scenario.