# How to delete fcm message already sent to end-user like messenger?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to archive delete fcm message from server side? For instance like Messenger(Facebook app), When you unsent a meesage they also delete notification that already shows up to end user, But I got no idea how they archive this. How they unsend a fcm message that already sent and deliver to end user?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do that, what you can do is you can store these messages on some kind of database and write logic to delete those messages which are seen by the user.
You can also see this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921958/can-you-expire-remove-a-message-remotely-on-fcm#:%7E:text=There%20is%20currently%20no%20way,successfully%20to%20the%20FCM%20server.)