# is there a way to remove or recall a push notification sent by fcm

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to remove or recall push notification already sent using FCM API
is there any way or workaround to delete or recall unread notification that sent via api

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `collapse_key` and replace the notification or yet send another notification with empty body.

Comment: but notification still already exist i need to remove it

Comment: @MohsenElzomor sorry, It's written 'to remove or recall' on the question description. btw, did you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140856/fcm-remove-older-push-notifcation-tiles-when-a-new-push-notiifcation-is-reciev/45141994#45141994

Comment: many thanks, i tried giving tag property with " " null title and body it's update the old title and body with " " but still notification already exist, is there any way to remove this notification instead of renotify?